# Python login feature and push notification

Tags: angularjs, django, postgresql, python-2.7

I need to create an admin login(admin for the website) and after admin login we need to send some push notification to the apps developed in ionic framework. I am bit confused from where i should start. I got a tutorial like https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial#learning-django-and-angularjs which says how can i create users. Python provide me different option for login when i check but i am not sure which is the best method and which should i follow. Please help me on this. THe database connection we need is a pstgresql and the web script should be written in angularjs.

Comment: Your starting point is Django restframework and recently also the Django Channels... Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, sending notifications to ios, and android is a bit different.

I was using couple of ready packages, but I found [THIS](https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notification) one the most useful, and user-friendly.

In order to send notifications to android devices, you have to have generated GCM API KEY (Google Cloud Messaging)

Same goes with iOs, but you need a certificate there as well.

You can write a custom login method, link it, and inside send a push notification. Let's say (custom method, can be written better, just an example)

```
def api_login(request):


if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.data.get('username', None)
    password = request.data.get('password', None)

    if not username or not password:
        return return_error(status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, "Login failed. Username or password missing or incorrect.")

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:                

            # DO YOUR JOB HERE, SEND PUSH NOTIFICATION
            # RETURN SOME MSG, TOKEN, OR ANYTHING :)

        else:

            return return_error(status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, "Login failed. User is inactive")

return return_error(status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, "Login failed. Login or password incorrect.")
```